# I get this error while using std::map. Why?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

When I try to compile the following code...

```
struct MemPages
{
  size_t size;
  volatile sig_atomic_t acc;
}; 

typedef std::map<unsigned long, MemPages> PagesMap;
PagesMap pagesMap;
............
pagesMap.insert(pair<unsigned long, MemPages>((unsigned long)addr, memPages ));
............
// This is Line 531
MemPages& mp = pagesMap[addr]; // Error here
```

I get the following error...

```
**replication.cpp:531: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘long unsigned int’
replication.cpp:531: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = long unsigned int, _Tp = MemPages, _Compare = std::less<long unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, MemPages> >]’
make: *** [all] Error 1**
```

Any Idea, what is going on?

Comment: If your keys are actually `void *` pointers, why are you converting them to `unsigned long`s?

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::map<void const*, MemPages>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says:

> invalid conversion from ‘`void*`’ to ‘`long unsigned int`’

`addr` is apparently a `void*`; the key type of your map is a `unsigned long`.  You need to pass an `unsigned long` (or, at least something that is convertible to an integer) to `operator[]`.

The casting of a pointer to an integer (`(unsigned long)addr`) in your code is odd:  there really shouldn't be any reason to do this.  If the key type of the `std::map` should be a pointer type, then you should make it a pointer type...

Comment: Ah, OK, I need to typecast the addr on line 531 too!

Comment: You typecast it for the first use *only*. In C++, a cast doesn't permanently change the type of the cast variable. Any future uses of `addr` use it as a `void *`, not as an `unsigned long`.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: Techncially  its possable for void* to be larger object than `unsigned long` so there is a potential for this to blow up. So why not just leave the key to your map as a void*? Then there would be no need to cast anything.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're casting `addr` (a `void *`, apparently?) to `unsigned long` in your insert, you also need to cast it on your retrieval.

The fact that you've cast `addr` somewhere in the code above doesn't mean that you've changed the fundamental datatype of the variable for later usage.  The cast only applies to that particular usage.  You'll need to cast it again wherever it needs to be treated as an `unsigned long`.

Comment: Yeah I know, I overlooked it :)!

Answer (score 1):

`pagesMap` is a map of `<unsigned long, MemPages>` your addr is of type `void*` and it needs to be of type `unsigned long`

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the `addr` argument to the map's *operator[]*

```
MemPages& mp = pagesMap[(unsigned long)addr];
```